# Failed to connect using XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration and setHost() with IP address

Tags: ip, xmpp, chat

I am trying to connect the ejabberd server from Java using the Smack API. When I am using the following code I could connect to the ejabberd server.

```
String server = "my server ip";
DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom(server);
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setHost(server)  method
                .setUsernameAndPassword("uname", "password")
                .setPort(5222)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                //.setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
                //.setHostAddress(addr)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .build();
        AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

        conn1.connect();

        if (conn1.isConnected()) {
            Log.d("XMPP", "Connected");
        }
        conn1.login();

        if (conn1.isAuthenticated()) {
            Log.d("XMPP", "Authenticated");
           /* EntityBareJid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("sadegh@localhost");
            org.jivesoftware.smack.chat2.Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn1).chatWith(jid);
            chat.send("Eureka, I am connected!");*/
        }
```

After executing the above code I got below error

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '157.230.160.183:5222' failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for 157.230.160.183.   IN  A yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN, '157.230.160.183:5222' failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for 157.230.160.183.   IN  AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:619)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:902)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:383)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at com.example.portalejabberddemo.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:94)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at com.example.portalejabberddemo.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:33)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at com.example.portalejabberddemo.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at com.example.portalejabberddemo.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-20 20:42:00.447 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-20 20:42:00.448 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
08-20 20:42:00.448 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-20 20:42:00.448 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-20 20:42:00.448 27072-27107/com.example.portalejabberddemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Smack, or MiniDNS to be precicse (the DNS library Smack uses) handles the IP you configure as host as literal DNS name. The reason is that you configure the host IP via `setHost(String)`, but `ConnectionConfiguration.Builder.setHost(String)` is only for DNS names. You either want to use:

- [`ConnectionConfiguration.Builder.setHostAddress(InetAddress)`](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.3.4/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.Builder.html#setHostAddress-java.net.InetAddress-)
- [`ConnectionConfiguration.Builder.setHostAddressByNameOrIp(CharSequence)`](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.3.4/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.Builder.html#setHostAddressByNameOrIp-java.lang.CharSequence-)

<sup>Note that future Smack versions may change the behavior of `setHost()` to also accept IP addresses.</sup>